# How can you tell if the browser was able to display file data using React

Tags: reactjs, file, display, detection

We have an application where the user can preview a file which is handled by passing the file data to an object tag: `<object data={URL.createObjectURL(data)} />`. The browser can display some file types natively like PDF or images, or may have extensions to display additional file types - docx, xslx, pptx,... Is there any way to detect if the browser was able to display the file?

Comment: Have you tried onError event?

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't actually have luck with onError, support is sketchy for object, but may work for audio, img, or video. But this led me to documentation for  [fallback content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#fallback-content) which is what I'm trying to do and eliminates the need for my question.